# Will a mesh front with three 120mm fans fitted in the O11 Dynamic Evo restrict access to the rads/distro plate?

Tags: desktop

I've been scouring the internet but can't find an answer to my question.

Planning on building my second water-cooled PC soon and I'm stuck between choosing the Corsair 5000T and O11 Dynamic Evo cases. Slightly leaning towards the 5000T but what would swing it towards the O11 case is the ability to fit a mesh front. My plan for the O11 build would be:

- 360 rad up top
- 360 rad on the bottom
- [This distro plate sitting on the back of the case](https://lian-li.com/product/o11d-distro-plate-g1/)
- A [mesh front](https://lian-li.com/product/o11de-4/) with x3 120mm fans

My only concern with the O11 Dynamic Evo with this setup is the space between the fans on the mesh front and access to the ports on the distro plate and rads. Anyone have any idea if the fans on the front mesh would restrict access to the rad ports / ports on the distro?